# Получение приватного поля в кастомном редакторе Unity через SerializedObject

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-editor

есть класс Property, в котором две приватные переменные - int и enum типов:

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class Property : ScriptableObject{


    [SerializeField] private PropertyTypes _propertyType;
    [SerializeField] private int _value;

    public PropertyTypes PropertyType { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }


}

public enum PropertyTypes
{
    lvl,
    hp,
    physicalAttack,
    magicAttack,
    physicalProtection,
    magicProtection,
    speed,
    xp,
    lp,
    honor
}
```

Есть так же класс(Properties), в котором есть лист этих классов.

Пишу редактор расширяющий класс Properties. До текущего момента все работало через получение публичных свойств. А вот сами приватные поля получить не могу.
Прочитал тут https://answers.unity.com/questions/1411189/expose-private-field-in-custom-editor.html  что вроде как это все надо делать через рефлексию, с которой я пока не знаком, начал о ней читать. Так же пишется что приоритетным способом является получение значений насколько я понял через то что является юнитевской обвязкой, предоставляющей тот же функционал. Пробую делать через него, но при вводе значения в инт поле оно автоматом сбрасывается.

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor.SceneManagement;

[CustomEditor(typeof(Properties))]
public class PropertyEditor : Editor
{
    Properties _propertyManager;

    public void OnEnable()
    {
        _propertyManager = (Properties)target;
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        if (_propertyManager.properties.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var property in _propertyManager.properties)
            {
                EditorGUILayout.BeginVertical("box");
                Property obj = ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<Property>();
                SerializedObject serializedObject = new SerializedObject(obj);
                SerializedProperty serializedPropertyValue = serializedObject.FindProperty("_value");
                serializedPropertyValue.intValue = EditorGUILayout.IntField("Значение", serializedPropertyValue.intValue);
                //old version property.PropertyType = (PropertyTypes)EditorGUILayout.EnumPopup("Имя параметра", property.PropertyType);
                Debug.Log(serializedPropertyValue.intValue);
                EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
                if (GUILayout.Button("X", GUILayout.Width(20), GUILayout.Height(20)))
                {
                    _propertyManager.properties.Remove(property);
                    break;
                }
                EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
                EditorGUILayout.EndVertical();

            }
        }
        else
        {
            EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Нет значений в листе");
        }

        if (GUI.changed)
        {            
            serializedObject.Update();
            serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
            Undo.RegisterCompleteObjectUndo(_propertyManager, "Change");
        }

        if (GUILayout.Button("Add"))
        {
            _propertyManager.properties.Add(ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<Property>());
        }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема у вас тут не совсем в значениях. Скорее в логике редактора.
`OnInspectorGUI` - вызывается каждый кадр, пока окно инспектора активно.
 `ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<Property>()` - создаёт новый экземпляр скрипт объекта (но не сохраняет его в папку ассетов).

Получается, вы каждый кадр создаёте новые скрипт объекты, меняете в них поля, а потом в следующем кадре опять создаёте новые объекты.

При этом `SerializedObject serializedObject = new SerializedObject(obj);` создаёт вам новый сериализуемый объект (кстати, лучше смените имя, т.к. в классе Editor есть такое поле для доступа к target приведённому к SerializedObject).

Вы создаёте новый объект, меняете у него поле, но не сохраняете в нём изменения после этого. Вам дополнительно нужна тут строчка `serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();` после модификации каждого `Property`. Чтобы применить ваши изменения для конкретно этого объекта.

Если вы хотите создавать новые ассеты из редактора вашего менеджера, то нужно добавить методы сохранения результата `ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<Property>()` в папку, т.к. без этого они остаются только в рамках метода, в котором вы их создали, как обычная переменная. Вам нужно использовать метод [`AssetDatabase.CreateAsset();`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.CreateAsset.html). Выглядеть это будет примерно так:

```
    if (GUILayout.Button("Add Property"))
    {
        Property obj = ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<Property>();
        AssetDatabase.CreateAsset(obj, "путь до папки");
        //здесь вы можете добавить только что созданный ассет в список менеджера
    }
```

Если вам потребуется отрисовать Enum поле, код для отдельного метода будет выглядеть, примерно так:

```
void DrowEnum(SerializedObject obj)
{
    SerializedProperty enumType = obj.FindProperty("_type");
    var curent = (EnyType)enumType.enumValueIndex;
    curent = (EnyType)EditorGUILayout.EnumPopup("Тип", curent);
    enumType.enumValueIndex = (int)curent;
}
```

Т.е. мы сначала ищем само поле у объекта. После чего получаем индекс текущего значения. Приводим этот индекс к типу-енуму. Отрисовываем его с помощью средств редактора. После чего приводим енум к индексу и записываем обратно в полученное поле.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Всю голову сломал почему так происходит. И инфы как то прям крохи по этому моменту, неужто никто не получает в кастомных редакторах значения приватных полей)

Comment: @phpred, ну, с полями вы, в принципе, правильно всё сделали. Просто усложнили тем, что писали редактор для другого скрип объекта, который содержит в себе ссылки на эти скрипт объекты)

Comment: Спасибо еще раз) буду разбираться) тема для меня новая. Я так понял тут еще с доступом к enum полю не все так просто будет, там только индекс можно получить как я вижу, а не доступ к значению сразу как например с int было, когда пишешь serializedPropertyValue.intValue и всего делов)

Comment: @phpred, enum по сути и является int-ом, если  вы при наследовании не укажете иного. При сериализации он сохраняет именно числовое порядковое значение, если вы не присвоите вручную каждому значению текстовому своё значение числовое. Сейчас в свой ответ добавлю, как его отрисовать можно

Comment: Вау! До такого бы точно не додумался) Я пытался там через приведение типов что то написать, но так и не понял как) Теперь у меня вся информация нужная мне, спасибо еще раз.